# Modal Dialog does not appear

Tags: codenameone

In my App I have an annoying behavior.  It is causing problems to my costumers.

The app has several points where I need to show a Dialog (Modal), then the users can fill some fields and then they can close the dialog. So the system follows its natural path.

In determined moments this works fine. The dialog is shown,  user interacts with it,  closes it , ....

But, in others moments (the same code) the dialog doesn't appear automatically. The user needs to execute some external action on device (like change its orientation, touch in the center of the screen, execute scroll gesture, etc). Some action that isn't intuitive at the moment.
This behavior makes the user think my app froze.
For me it is clear that the dialog was called, simply it wasn't  drawed on the screen.

I tryed read about this problem.I did some researches in similar questions without success.
I guess the cause is related  to EDT.

In short, How can I call a Dialog Modal without breaking EDT-rules.
And more specifically, How can I resolve this problem.
when I request a dialog to be displayed on the screen, I want it really appears in 100% of cases. Today works randomly.

Additional infomations:
My app uses Java 5 yet.
Do you recommends migration to Java 8?

======= Additional Informations (1) ===========

This problem is strongly dependent of device model.
In MotoG3 (Android 6) this problem is a exception. Rarely it occurs.
In my Galaxy Note 8 is the  opposite. Always occurs.
In Lenovo Vibe5 (Android 6). Frequently occurs.
I added these informations. Maybe it help to compound problem picture.

Additional question:
Is it  possible write a snippet that I can use as a template
to execute Dialog Modal call without break some rule of EDT?

Comment: Yes, migrate to Java 8.  The last java 5 release was 7 years ago.  Its going to be a pain though...

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on the EDT violation detection tool in the simulator which should detect such issues. Inspect potentially problematic cases of `Dialog` calls and post them specifically if you don't know how to fix them.

Java 8 is unrelated although migrating a project is non-trivial.

Comment: Hi Shai.
Using Simulator I can't handle with that issue. Bidirectional communication between Javascript and Java doesn't work. (I don't know why too. But this is other problem).  Can I use adb (from Android-sdk) and getting  access to EDT violations directly from logcat-device? Bidirectional communication works fine when app is executing on physical devices.
This problem happens exactly in java code that is called from javascript.

Comment: Java code that is called from JavaScript will probably be invoked on the native browser thread. To interact with the UI you will need a callSerially().

Comment: I did this. I already tried to call Dialog using Display CallSerially(). The result was worse. An exception reporting EDT violations with the following message: An internal application error occurred: java.lang.RunTimeException: This method MUST NOT be invoked on EDT.

Comment: Did you call callSeriallyAndWait? In that case it could be caused because a different block of code is showing a form. If this only happens on the device you can use logging to debug that.

Comment: Sorry, I used long time to add a new comment. It was necessary because the problem has device dependences and happens randomly.
The comment from Shai resolved the problem. Using "Display CallSerially()" the  Dialog now always appear. But another strange behavior appeared after. Some touch events that are performed on the Dialog Box are also being processed by the Form under the Dialog. What is expected is the Dialog Modal blocks the event inside itself.

Comment: I suggest accepting this answer and filing a different question with details/screeshots etc. It's hard to understand what you are asking

Comment: Yes. The main question was answered. The Modal Dialog now always appear.
Other problem appeared after and it is better open another specific question for it.